# Tools to draw ER diagrams (tried visio, smartdraw, but didn't work)

Tags: database-design, er-diagram

I'd like to draw something like below. 
http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/7/72/ER_Diagram_MMORPG.png

I've Visio, SmartDraw, MySQL workbench, etc. All of them were missing shapes like double lines, weak entity, identifying relationship (double line diamond box), etc.

I don't find a single tool which has all of them. Please suggest one.

Answer (score 2):

You won't believe it, but I often use plain Excel for diagrams. [Nice tutorial here](http://www.breezetree.com/articles/how-to-flow-chart-in-excel.htm). It works also without their proposed add-in.

Answer (score 1):

I know its a long shot but StarUML. Thats what i did my ER diagrams in in the first year of uni... its free but you need to play about to find what your looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Visio has everything in it, you just need to check under all kinds. As per those double lines, you could just insert two of the same shapes, decrease size or overlap them and group them to use again by copy pasting.